How to play notes on android using Midi Simplified 1.6 (Firemonkey)?
I'm making new version my software cifracil (cifracil.com). Its a editor interpret lryrics and chords , find chords in dictionary and draw diagrams chrods. I put a new feature. User cam make a tablature and set musical simbols to each note. Software play tablatura notes. I'm using Delphi Firemonkey . I'm using Midi Simplified 1.6 components in firemonkey to play notes and its working fine. Windows has Microsoft Gs Wavetable Synth , than i can send noteon and noteoff . But Android does not have default synth . I ask chatgp and it suggest instal FluidSynth app as Outpud Device. This code works in windows .
VetNotes := SplitString(FSeqPlay[i].notas,';');
for j := Low(VetNotes) to High(VetNotes) do
begin
    NotaMid := NotaParaMidi(VetNotes[j]); // midi note
       if Assigned(Midi) then // assigned device
          Midi.SendMIDINoteOn(0,notamid,127);
 end;

I expected a solution to use Simplified 1.6 component working on android. If there is other solution, i can try too. But i belive its possible use simplifield component. I need understand how use a output on android.
